# Is it possible to clear the terminal with Term::ReadKey?

Tags: perl, module, console, screen

Is there a way to do this with the Term::ReadKey-module?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Term::Screen;

say( "Hello!\n" x 5 );
sleep 2;

my $scr = Term::Screen->new();
$scr->clrscr();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term%3a%3aReadKey) would provide such a feature or if it does. But, how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

*clrscr = $^O eq 'MSWin32'
        ? sub { system('cls') }
        : sub { system('clear') };

print "Hello\n" for 1 .. 5;
sleep 2;
clrscr();
```

Comment: I suppose I've read something wrong. Don't remember where. So I will stick with Term::Screen and use system('clear') as backup.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to use `Term::Readkey` for clearing the screen. It definitely does not have that capability. Are you trying to use something that's part of the standard Perl installation? You can use Term::Caps which is part of the standard Perl installation. Unfortunately, it requires the Termcaps file to be on the system, and Windows doesn't have that.

```
use Term::Cap;

#
# Use eval to catch the error when TERM isn't defined or their is no
# Termcap file on the system.
#
my $terminal;
eval {$terminal = Term::Cap->Tgetent();};

#
# Use 'cl' to get the Screen Clearing sequence
#

if ($@) {  #Most likely a Windows Terminal
    system('cls');            #We really should be doing the 2 line below
    # my $clear = "\e[2J";    #But, it doesn't seem to work.
    # print "$clear";         #Curse You! I'll get you yet Bill Gates!
} else {   #A Real Computer
    my $clear = $terminal->Tputs('cl');
    print "$clear";
}
print "All nice and squeeky clean!\n";
```

I tried printing the ANSI Escape sequence if it was a Windows Terminal, but it  doesn't seem to work.

I hate doing system calls because there is a security risk . What if someone changed the `cls` command on you?

Answer (score 0):

[`Term::Readkey`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey) does not provide this function directly, but usually the key combination to clear the screen in a Terminal is `^L` (Control-L):

| Binary | Oct | Dec | Hex | Asc | Sym | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001100 | 14 | 12 | c | ff | ^L | Form Feed (Next Page) |

So, if you want to build this in to your application using that module, you can do something like this:

```perl
use Term::ReadKey;

# Perform a normal read using getc

my $key = ReadKey( 0 );

# If ^L was pressed, clear the screen

if ( ord $key == 12 ) { print "\e[2J" }
```

The above example uses the raw escape sequence `\e[2J` which clears the entire screen.  You also have the following alternatives:

| Sequence | Function |
| --- | --- |
| `\e[J` | Clears from cursor until end of screen |
| `\e[0J` | Clears from cursor until end of screen |
| `\e[1J` | Clears from cursor to beginning of screen |
| `\e[2J` | Clears entire screen |
| `\e[K` | Clears from cursor to end of line |
| `\e[0K` | Clears from cursor to end of line |
| `\e[1K` | Clears from cursor to start of line |
| `\e[2K` | Clears entire line |

The escape code `\e` refers to ASCII character number 27:

| Binary | Oct | Dec | Hex | Asc | Sym | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00011011 | 33 | 27 | 1b | esc | ^[ | Escape |

See [VT100 Escape Sequences](https://espterm.github.io/docs/VT100%20escape%20codes.html) for more information.

This should even work if you're using Windows, since [apparently this works there nowadays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).